# CSS Background transparency without affecting child element using LESS

Tags: jquery, html, css, less, opacity

I found many solutions on the internet,Stackoverflow and tried but nothing can't solve my problem. I'm using FontAwesome and LESS on my website but when I added font-icon, it affected by the opacity (rgba) of parent element. Here is my code:

http://codepen.io/thehung1724/pen/Lxjcl

Hope anyone can help me out. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the before!!! In you code pen i removed the before and applied the styles to the icon container. Then background color of the parent stayed with transparency, and the icon don´t!! :)

```
  .icon-container{

  &:before{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 8px;
    top: 5px;
    .rotate(45deg);
    .rgba(black, 0.4);
    z-index:1;
  }

  span{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
  }


  &:nth-child(n){
    filter: none;
  }
```

Comment: Thank @legues. I'm using Fontawesome in demo, actually I created custom font-icon with using <span> tag instead <i> tag. If I remove before, icon will also rotate too. How can I fix this?

Comment: I´ve updated my answer!! :) If the icon rotates too, just force the span rotate 0 degrees!! :)

Comment: are you using span or i?

Comment: As I told, I'm using <span> tag. Why <i> tag doesn't affected rotate?

Comment: But a span to wrapp the I?

Comment: here is my code: <div class="icon-container"><span class="icon icon-camera"></span></div>

Comment: Ok, i´ve also updated the above code! I´ve putted the before again, but the span it´s not with the relative position. Then the z-index will fix all the rest!!! :)

Comment: I tried but nothing changed but I've fixed my problem by using negative rotate.